# Rewrite request to query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these lines in my `.htaccess`, and it works as I want it to.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api$ page.php?id=api
```

If you go to `http://example.com/api`, it would rewrite the URL as `http://example.com/page.php?id=api`, but I need this to apply to any alphanumeric input, for instance:

```
No request:
    http://example.com -> http://example.com/page.php?id=
Anything else:
    http://example.com/foobar123 -> http://example.com/page.php?id=foobar123
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The value of `$_GET["id"]` is equal to `page.php`.

Comment: if you ask example.com/page.php  -  yes. Or you have some line before in htaccess that do any other redirection

Comment: I have no other redirection rules.

Comment: Sorry - i forgot say that it's last rule - [L]